# How to keep Z-order of a control in MFC dialog?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

it starts driving me nuts, but I cann't figure out how to keep position of a child control in a z-order.
At design time in MFC dialog resource editor I have STATIC control (descendant of CStatic) at the bottom (tab order Nr. 1), ie. it's overlapped by other controls like buttons, listbox etc.

At runtime, dialog handles WM_TIMER message and in OnTimer handler there gets the STATIC control moved:

```
void CTestMFCDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
  ...
  m_stMyStatic.SetWindowPos(&this->wndBottom, xpos, ypos, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
  ...
}
```

After the call of SetWindowPos for the sublassed CStatic control, it's drawed over other controls in a dialog, no matter what I'm passing in the first argument.

Any idea how to keep the control at the bottom of Z-order all the time ?

Comment: Do you have `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style in your dialog? If not, the controls may draw above each other regardless to z-order. Anyway, you should check the **actual** z-order of your windows (by win-spy).

Comment: Clip siblings property of a dialog is set to true. I did inspected the running app with Spy++ but not found where can I read about control's z-order.

Comment: Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160105/how-can-you-bring-a-control-to-front-in-mfc

Comment: @Michael> Unfortunately this does not covers my issue, ie. ignoring z-order after a control changes its topleft coordinates.

Comment: @David Unric - Spy++ orders sibling controls by Z-order in the Windows view.  Also, selecting properties, the Prev Window and Next Window indicate Z-order

Answer (score 2):

The answer is plain simple. I did just overlooked one flag in SetWindowPos documentation.
To prevent z-order changing just pass **SWP_NOZORDER** flag, so the function call should look like:

```
m_stMyStatic.SetWindowPos(NULL, xpos, ypos, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```